# Keep PPCG running in Game of Life

Tags: code-challenge, cellular-automata, busy-beaver, game-of-life

[Conways' Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) is a well known cellular automaton "played" on an infinite grid, filled with cells that are either alive or dead. Once given an initial state, the board evolves according to rules indefinitely. Those rules are:

- Any live cell with 2 or 3 living neighbours (the 8 cells immediately around it) lives to the next state
- Any dead cell with exactly 3 living neighbours becomes a living cell
- Any other cell becomes a dead cell

Consider the following initial state:

[image]

That is, `PPCG` made up of living cells. Each letter is in a \$4×6\$ bounding box, with a single empty column of cells between boxes, for a total bounding box of \$19×6\$

After 217 generations, it reaches the following states:

[image]

From this point onwards, it is a "fixed state". All structures on the board are either still lifes or oscillators, so no meaningful change will occur.

Your task is to improve this.

[image]

You may place up to 50 live cells in the \$5\times10\$ highlighted area, such that, when run, it takes more than 217 generations to reach a "fixed state". The answer with the highest number of generations wins, with ties being broken by the fewest number of placed living cells.

For the purposes of this challenge, a "fixed state" means that all structures on the board are either still lifes or oscillators. If any spaceships or patterns of infinite growth are generated, the board will never reach a "fixed state" and such cases are invalid submissions.

For example, this initial configuration takes 294 generations to reach a fixed state ([this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPIL8.png)), so is a valid submission with a score of 294:

[image]

[Preloaded](http://copy.sh/life/?gist=459828da945d707ff37e046dcf90c106) testable version, with the \$5\times10\$ box fully filled in.

Comment: It's not difficult to beat the 294 example, but brownie points for beating my best shot of 797 iterations!

Comment: Next challenge: add outside cells to turn `PPCG` into `CGCC` with minimal number of iterations :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo Obviously the title would be "Graduate PPCG in Game of Life" :P

Comment: Are there techniques here other than brute force?

Comment: @Jonah I believe so. The [original idea on Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31247/game-of-life-kill-the-sun) was solved without using brute force, so I suspect that, due to the smaller area, proper analysis is likely to lead to a better solution faster

Comment: @Makonede Yes, the preloaded version is simply there so that people can easily set up their own attempts, without trying to figure out where the box is on a grid with no gridlines. To get the 217 version, try deselecting all 50 of the box cells

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly Nevermind, I just noticed that any submissions that never reach fixed states are invalid.

Comment: I found a pattern that lasts roughly 3450 generations, not counting the ten gliders it sends off along the way :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 3365 generations

```
_#_#_
##__#
_##__
_____
#####
_##__
#____
#_#_#
##___
_#_#_
```

This 5x10 start can be expressed as 379744881760010 in decimal, 159603ec8570a in hex or 01010 11001 01100 00000 11111 01100 10000 10101 11000 01010 in 50-bit binary. Crossing my fingers that nobody starts a new alt-coin based on rewarding many generations in Conway's Game of Life...LifeCoins.

Answer (score 14):

## 2986 <s>2320</s> <s>1228</s> generations

I wrote a rudimentary Python script for [Golly](http://golly.sourceforge.net) to generate random 5x10 patterns until it encountered one whose population was fixed, and whose bounding box was not too large (as would be expected of soups containing spaceships, as spaceships expand the bounding box as they travel). Here was what it came up with after about 50,000 patterns investigated, and I suspect this is not maximal. If anyone wants to continue this search by using my script, it's located below the pattern.

[image]

RLE of solution:

```
# 2986 generations
x = 19, y = 20, rule = B3/S23
3o2b3o3b3o2b3o$o2bobo2bobo4bo$o2bobo2bobo4bo$3o2b3o2bo4bob2o$o4bo4bo4b
o2bo$o4bo5b3o2b2o5$7bobobo$7b2ob2o$8bo2bo$11bo$10b2o$7bo2bo2$8b4o$7bo$
7bo3bo!
```

Python script, to be run in Golly from File > Run Script (not golfed). You will need to paste/draw in the PPCG pattern and select the 5x10 rectangle first.

```python
import golly as g
from glife import rect, pattern

g.setrule("B3/S23") #set the rule to Conway's Life
soupcount = 0 #create a counter for # of soups processed

while True:
    pop = 0
    g.randfill(50) #randomly fill the 5x10 selection
    g.run(2400) #run the pattern for 2400 generations
    if g.getrect()[2] * g.getrect()[3] < 40000: #after 2400 generations, if the bounding box is small
        pop = g.getpop() #check to make sure the population is not the same (pattern is not static)
        g.run(120)
        if g.getpop() != pop:
            g.run(9880) #after 9880 more generations, if the bounding box is still small
            if g.getrect()[2] * g.getrect()[3] < 40000: #check to make sure the population is the same (pattern is static)
                pop = g.getpop()
                g.run(120)
                if g.getpop() == pop:
                    g.reset() #if so, break the loop and return the pattern
                    break
    g.reset() #repeat the loop and generate a new pattern if the pattern does not satisfy the conditions
    soupcount += 1
    g.show(str(soupcount)) #continually show the # of soups processed to make sure the program isn't dead
```

**RLEs of old solutions:**

```
#C 2320 generations
x = 19, y = 20, rule = B3/S23
3o2b3o3b3o2b3o$o2bobo2bobo4bo$o2bobo2bobo4bo$3o2b3o2bo4bob2o$o4bo4bo4b
o2bo$o4bo5b3o2b2o5$7bo3bo$7b3o$10bo2$7bo$7bo2bo$7bo$7b2o$7bo3bo$7b2o2b
o!
```

```
#C 1228 generations, found manually with Ctrl+5
#C to continually generate random 5x10 patterns
x = 19, y = 17, rule = B3/S23
3o2b3o3b3o2b3o$o2bobo2bobo4bo$o2bobo2bobo4bo$3o2b3o2bo4bob2o$o4bo4bo4b
o2bo$o4bo5b3o2b2o5$7b5o$7bobobo$7b2obo$8bob2o$8b4o$8bo2bo$7bobo!
```

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI I'm not sure what you mean, could you explain?

Comment: @OriginalOriginalOriginalVI The last score is 2986. The higher, the better.

Comment: @Arnauld Oh, I see, I didn't bother looking at the first one :)

Comment: I just noticed that I typed `from glife import rect, pattern` and then completely failed to use it any way. In my defense, it was my first time writing a Golly script, so I was copying the imports from another program. Oops!

Answer (score 8):

## 887 generations

[image: Solution]

## Explanation

…There is no explanation. I just brute-forced it manually and somehow beat ChartZ Belatedly by 90 generations.

Answer (score 5):

## <s>884</s>  900 generations

Just some random handcrafted pattern.

[image: pattern]

Comment: Beat you by 5 seconds and 3 iterations... :)

Answer (score 4):

## <s>3020</s> 3179 Generations

```
# #  
### #
 # # 
   ##
##   
    #
     
    #
 # ##
##
```

Found by random search

Comment: Yup, I also got 3020 on this one! (my own best so far is 851)

Comment: I regret to inform you that there are thirty blinkers in the ash of that soup. Nice work in beating me, though!

Comment: @Cloudy7 – Oscillators are okay says the challenge. I'm guessing those the same as blinkers (typically a bar of 3 vertical or 3 horizontal). Inits that leads to gliders/spaceships that continue forever are invalid, but this submission didn't have any of those.

Comment: @KjetilS. They claimed that the final pattern "reaches a still life with no oscillators".

Comment: @Cloudy7 – Oh, I see now. Yes, that wasn't so, but we seem to agree that the submission is okay.

Comment: @Cloudy7 Oops, I didn't realize that the copy.sh game of life implementation step function doesn't single step